# unicode glyph in svgfont not displayed by Firefox (works fine with Chrome and Opera)

Tags: firefox, unicode, svg

I used Batik to convert a cursive Google web font into an SVG font which I later on embedded into the SVG document. I have to extend the SVG font because it cannot display some characters with diacritics so I created a new glyph for the letter "ă" (a with breve).

It shows fine in Chrome and Opera (IE9 I don't know) but it doesn't work in Firefox. In Firefox the character from the  tag is displayed with a fall-back font looking like a goose amidst the hens.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 ....
 <glyph
     unicode="ă"
     glyph-name="ă"
     horiz-adv-x="851"
     d="M553 582H709L630 ... 280.161,824.3825 Z"
     id="glyph144" />
```

I tried also setting the `unicode` attrb to `&#x0103`.

I am using the latest release from Firefox (9.0) in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither [IE](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2010/08/microsoft-releases-final-internet-explorer-9-platform-preview.ars) nor [Firefox](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/08/18/why-firefox-is-not-scoring-100-in-the-acid3-test/) implement SVG fonts. They instead concentrate on WOFF. There has been a bit of debate on the www-svg mailing list over that since WOFF doesn't address some use cases SVG fonts have.

But from what I see from the spec your code is actually correct and should work in conforming implementations.

Comment: Yes, it should, because the rest of the glyphs are displayed as defined in the svg font, except this Unicode character. So I would say that Firefox is supporting svg fonts partially unless there is some quirk that I am missing.

Comment: That would be very odd.  Firefox has no support for SVG fonts at all at the moment.  Do you have a testcase?

Comment: My guess would be that the (allegedly) SVG font would also be a locally-present one, except for the missing glyph.